# How to return columns from a Dataframe in a function that were not calculated by the function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have the following Dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df_county = pd.DataFrame({
                        "A": [50],
                        "B": [60],
                        "C": [70]})
df_voronoi = pd.DataFrame({
                        "area": [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
                        "county": ["A", "B", "C", "A"],
                        "bus":["bus1", "bus4", "bus20", "bus2"]})
```

With the following function I am calculating my values:

```
def calc(df1, df2):
    return [1/(df1[county] / area) for county,area in zip(df2.county, df2.area)]

df=calc(df_county,df_voronoi)
df=pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df)
```

Result:

[image]

Here  `county` is the index. I want to have `county` as a own column and I want to have the `bus`-column from the Voronoi-Dataframe as a column with the right relation to the `county` and `area`.

Thas means i would like to have an output from the function that looks like this:

[image]

How to realize that?

And an extra question:
Does it matter at what position I define the function? I have an example where the function is created at the top and the type of the return is a pandas Dataframe. In this example it's a list and I have to make a Dataframe from the list. If yes, can you explane me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a small modification to your existing structure.Try this

```
import pandas as pd


df_county = pd.DataFrame({
                        "A": [50],
                        "B": [60],
                        "C": [70]})
df_voronoi = pd.DataFrame({
                        "area": [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
                        "country": ["A", "B", "C", "A"],
                        "bus":["bus1", "bus4", "bus20", "bus2"]})



def calc(df1, df2):
    return [(1/(df1[country] / area),area) for country,area in zip(df2.country, df2.area)]

df=calc(df_county,df_voronoi)
mdf= pd.DataFrame([f[0] for f in df]).reset_index()
mdf["area"]= [f[1] for f in df]
mdf.columns = ["country","factor","area"]
print(mdf)

  country     factor  area
0       A  20.000000  1000
1       B  33.333333  2000
2       C  42.857143  3000
3       A  80.000000  4000
```

added area column,otherwise we can't identify which bus we need(since two A in df2)

```
merged = pd.merge(mdf,df_voronoi,on=["country","area"],how="left")
merged = merged.drop(columns=["area"])
print(merged)

  country     factor    bus
0       A  20.000000   bus1
1       B  33.333333   bus4
2       C  42.857143  bus20
3       A  80.000000   bus2
```

Comment: mdf output isn't working! Error message: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: use print(mdf) to view the structure.. i have changed few things in your code.return tuple in calc function,and changed `county` to `country`.i dont get any error.